# Nested loop code to create right triangle in Python

Tags: python, loops, nested, geometry

Professor gave us a simple code that executes a square and we need to add/change the code to output the right triangle shape as shown below. It's just a simple loop within a loop code, but I can't find tips or help anywhere for creating shapes with Python without the code looking extremely confusing/difficult. I need a simple explanation what to do and why I need to make those changes.

(Nested loop code to create right triangle in Python)

The code given that executes a square:

## Draw Square

```
size = input('Please enter the size: ')
chr  = raw_input('Please enter the drawing character: ')

row = 1
while row <= size:
    # Output a single row
    col = 1
    while col <= size:
        # Output a single character, the comma suppresses the newline output
        print chr, 
        col = col + 1

    # Output a newline to end the row
    print '' 

    row = row + 1
print ''
```

The shape I need to output.....

```
x 
x x 
x x x 
x x x x 
x x x x x 
x x x x x x 
x x x x x x x
```

Once again, just a simple code explanation, it's an introduction to Python course.

Comment: If your code actually works, but you want to improve it, this question should be migrated to [codereview.se]; if it does not work, please clarify what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Just change `while col <= size:` to `while col <= row:`

This will print out `row` number of `X`.

If `row`is `1`the ouput is: X

If `row`is `2`the ouput is: X X

If `row`is `3`the ouput is: X X X

If `row`is `4`the ouput is: X X X X

Comment: That's wonderful thank you. I did not think it would be that simple with all the difficult examples I've found online thus far.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code:

```
size = int(raw_input("Enter the size: ")) #Instead of input, 
#convert it to integer!
char = raw_input("Enter the character to draw: ")
for i in range(1, size+1):
    print char*i #on the first iteration, prints 1 'x'
    #on the second iteration, prints 2 'x', and so on
```

Result:

```
>>> char = raw_input("Enter the character to draw: ")
Enter the character to draw: x
>>> size = int(raw_input("Enter the size: "))
Enter the size: 10
>>> for i in range(1, size+1):
        print char*i


x
xx
xxx
xxxx
xxxxx
xxxxxx
xxxxxxx
xxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
```

Also, avoid using `input` in Python 2, as it evaluates the string passed as *code*, it's unsafe and a bad practice.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I did not realize that. I will try to keep that in mind, but so far all I've been taught is to use input.

Comment: If you use Python 2, use `raw_input`. Your professor probably didn't think of this as an important thing, but in real application this can be crucial.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
def triangle(i, t=0):
    if i == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        print ' ' * ( t + 1 ) + '*' * ( i * 2 - 1 )
        return triangle( i - 1, t + 1 )
triangle(5)
```

Output:

```
* * * * * * * * *
   * * * * * * *
     * * * * *
       * * * 
         *
```

Answer (score 0):

```
values = [0,1,2,3]
for j in values:
 for k in range (j):
  print "*",;
 print "*";
```

1. define array
2. start first for loop to one by one initialize values of array in variable j
3. start second (nested) for loop to initialize ranje of variable j in variable k
4. end second (nested) for loop to print * as par initialized range of j assigned to k i.e. if range is 1 then print one *
5. end first for loop and print * for no of initialized array

Answer (score 0):

```py
for i in range(1,8):
    stars=""
    for star in range(1,i+1):
        stars+= " x"
    print(stars)
```

Output:

```
x
x x
x x x
x x x x
x x x x x
x x x x x x
x x x x x x x
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got this in a lab and figured i would post my solution

```
chrter = input('Input Character ', )
tri_height = int(input('Input Triangle Height ', ))

new_chrter = ''
for i in range(1, tri_height + 1):
    new_chrter += chrter + ' '
    print(new_chrter)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 def pattStar():
     print 'Enter no. of rows of pattern'
     noOfRows=input()
     for i in range(1,noOfRows+1):
             for j in range(i):
                     print'*',
             print''
```

Comment: Could you try to explain a little bit about your answer? It would be nice to see a *bit* of explanation here.

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

```
for x in range(10,0,-1):
  print x*"*"
```

output:

```
**********
*********
********
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: if you want to pass a single statement with in for loop ,you can pass it in a single line , like i did                for x in range(10,0,-1):print x * "*"    it is using the operation that we use in strings i.e *(multiplication operator on string ) to perform repetitions.It works fine ,as a one line code for printing inverted right angled traingle.

Answer (score -2):

you can obtain it by simply use this:

```
size = input('Please enter the size: ')
chr  = raw_input('Please enter the drawing character: ')
i=0
str =''
while i< size:
        str = str +' '+ chr
        print str
        i=i+1
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.